# Trying to view XSLT HTML page with JavaScript transformations

Tags: html, javascript, xml, xslt

I have a web site that is not showing its content. This content is in XML format and with a XSLT presentation.
There's some JavaScript to convert the code from the XML to HTML presentation. According to the user this was accessible a few months ago but now it's not working.

Any idea what the problem is?

I'm assuming it's a problem with the Internet Explorer config or version and that some changes now do not allow viewing the content.

I placed the code in this pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/Jmh85pTU

Comment: http://www.geap.com.br/download/pagamento/HTML/GEAPDEM_11084514_00.HTML this is the url for the html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens because the JavaScript code isn't readable in Internet Explorer bigger then 8.

I managed to go around the issue by emulating Internet Explorer 8

Here's the link I followed to do the emulation.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/how-can-i-test-my-web-site-in-ie6-ie7-ie8-and-ie9